# Main theorem of Pythagorean plane

Tags: geometry, reference-request

The theorem states:

Any Pythagorean plane is isomorphic to the Cartesian plane $F^2$ over its field $F$ of segments.

Can anyone give me a reference for this theorem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am surmising that your definition for a Pythagorean plane is the same as mine, i.e. the one in Greenberg's [excellent article](http://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/22/Ford/Greenberg2011.pdf).

That is precisely what Hilbert carried out in his book [*Foundations of geometry*](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/17384).

This book is free to the public online at the Project Gutenberg link above. It is not the most modern prose, but it's readable and at a good level of rigor.

I think I've heard some people dissatisfied with some details in Hilbert's book, so if you find that's the case, check in Hartshorne's [*Euclid and beyond*](http://books.google.com/books/about/Geometry_Euclid_and_Beyond.html?id=EJCSL9S6la0C). It's a great read and I believe it also produces the proof you want.